# Why do some "finite versions" of contravariant constructions become covariant?

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology

If we look at the De Rham cohomology of a space, the normal functor $H^n$ is contravariant. Yet when we restrict our attention to those forms which have compact support, the resulting functor $H^n_C$ is covariant.

Similarly, for a fixed field $K$, the functor $K^{(-)}$ sending a set $X$ to the vector space of functions $X \to K$ is contravariant... until one restricts attention to functions defined on a finite subset of $X$. The new functor $K[-]$ is the free vector space with basis $X$, and is a covariant functor.

One can also use abelian groups, and consider $\mathbb{Z}^X$ vs $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as above, but this doesn't feel like a really new example.

---

Is there some general principle here? Or am I reading too far into things? The proofs that $H^n_C$ and $K[-]$ are covariant are relatively different, so this observation may be a coincidence. Obviously there is some generalization from $K$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ as above into general free $R$-modules, but I'm curious if there is anything more.

---

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: A functor isn't determined solely by its action on objects. It doesn't make sense to say a functor goes from being contravariant to covariant just by restricting the domain. The action on arrows of $K^{(-)}$ and $K[-]$ are quite different even if the action on objects are the same.

Comment: As to why this coincidence of objects happen, as you intuit, at least for the latter two cases we can generalize to arbitrary $R$-modules. The category of $R$-modules for a commutative ring (with identity) $R$ is abelian and thus additive. All additive categories have *finite* biproducts meaning finite products and finite coproducts coincide. Since every set is a coproduct of singletons and the free $R$-module functor is a left adjoint, every free $R$-module is a copower of $F(1)\cong R$ and thus, in the finite set case, also a power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a long story. There are two distinct but related phenomena here:

1. Many contravariant constructions can be thought of as "pulling back" functions or some variation of functions along maps $f : X \to Y$ of "spaces" in some sense. In special cases this "pulling back" operation can be reversed into a "pushforward" operation which, loosely speaking, is given by "integration along the fibers" of $f$, which isn't always possible.
2. Some constructions come in two flavors, a contravariant "function" version (that pulls back) and a covariant "distribution" version (that pushes forward), and sometimes the "distribution" version looks like a "compact support" version of the "function" version.

The easiest version of this occurs when $X, Y$ are sets. Then:

1. If $K$ is, say, a commutative ring, then we can pull back functions $K^Y \to K^X$ along maps $f : X \to Y$ of sets. If $f$ has finite fibers, then we can also push forward functions, as follows: if $r \in K^X$ is a function, then define the pushforward $f_{\ast}(r) \in K^Y$ to be the function $f_{\ast}(r)(y) = \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} r(x)$. Note that pullback is a ring homomorphism but pushforward isn't; this is typical.
2. Again if $K$ is a commutative ring, then instead of functions $K^X$ we can work with functions with finite support $K[X]$, and these push forward (and don't pull back). From the point of view of algebraic topology this is zeroth homology $H_0(X, K)$, whereas functions are zeroth cohomology $H^0(X, K)$. Note that $H^0$ is the linear dual of $H_0$ and pullback is the dual of pushforward.

For more complicated variations see e.g. [cohomology with compact support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_with_compact_support), [compactly supported distributions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+supported+distribution), and [fiber integration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+integration). This stuff is relevant, for example, for generalizing Poincaré duality to noncompact manifolds.

Here is a variation where no compactness / finiteness is necessary: if $f : X \to Y$ is a map between sets, we get a pullback $P(Y) \to P(X)$ from subsets of $Y$ to subsets of $X$ given by taking preimages. But we also have a pushforward given by taking images, with no additional hypotheses. These are adjoint in the categorical sense, thinking of the poset of subsets as a category; also note that pullback is a homomorphism of Boolean algebras but pushforward isn't.

There's a further categorical variation of this story where the things we're pushing forward and pulling back are variations of [sheaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)).